# How to get the changes promoted to already promoted ref

Tags: git

I usually works on the feature branch, due to some issue, I checked out to previous commit/merged version. By mistake, rather committing my code to feature branch, I checked-in the new changes into merged ref(asdas1123).

Is there a way how I can get back my changes. Push is not happening, just a local commit happened on this ref(asdas1123).

Example:

```
-- feature branch
  --- because of some issue switched to the previous commit version. -- asdas1123
      -- by mistake new changes committed to asdas1123.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the commit made on the wrong branch to the correct one (assuming here only *one* commit was created)
- reset the wrong branch HEAD to `HEAD~`

So:

```
git checkout feature
git cherry-pick <commit from asdas1123>
# if the commit is the last one from asdas1123, use the branch name to reference its HEAD
git cherry-pick asdas1123

git checkout asdas1123
git reset --hard @~
```

Comment: am getting this error git cherry-pick asdas1123
error: commit asdas1123 is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: cherry-pick failed

Comment: The changes I promoted locally was not a branch, its already merged ref

Comment: @M-S then don't use the branch name (whose HEAD reference a merge commit), but the SHA1 of the commit you have added. Did you add a stand-alone commit? Or did you mix your changes in a working tree ending up being part of a merge commit?